# @Published class has no member .store | Combine SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Trying to solve the challenge from the milestone via `Combine`, but stuck on a error:

```
Value of type 'Published<[User]>.Publisher' has no member 'store'
```

Source code:

```swift
import Combine
import Foundation


// MARK: Main model from API
struct User: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let company: String
    let email: String
    let address: String
    let about: String
    let registered: Date
    let tags: [String]
    let friends: [Friend]
}

// MARK: - Friend array API
struct Friend: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = [User]()

    private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    // Error: Value of type 'Published<[User]>.Publisher' has no member 'store'
    init() { $model.store(in: &subscriptions )}
}

extension ViewModel {
    // MARK: - Make request to API
    func fetch() -> AnyPublisher<User, Error> {
        guard let mainURL = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json") else {
            fatalError("404: Not found")
        }

        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: mainURL)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

I don't understand, where do I need to create a Publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account your other code, here is usage (compiled with Xcode 11.4)

```
init() {
  self.fetch()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
        // do here whatever needed with error
    }, receiveValue: { [weak self] user in
        self?.model.append(user)
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your struct user has no store. Therefore you are trying to add something to your struct that is not existing. Take a look at your struct, no store there:

```
struct User: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let company: String
    let email: String
    let address: String
    let about: String
    let registered: Date
    let tags: [String]
    let friends: [Friend]
}
```